# How would you recommend further improving this "the eggs take longer than the pizza" solution?

Tags: eggs, pizza, cooking-time, frozen

Based on the incredible answers and discussion here [Resolve a "the eggs take longer than the pizza" issue?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/125313/resolve-a-the-eggs-take-longer-than-the-pizza-issue)

After a few experiments it does seem to be the case that incredibly

- eggs for 4 minutes on a scalding pizza

cooks the eggs MUCH, MUCH more than

- eggs for 14 minutes on an ice pizza

So a totally frozen frozen-type pizza:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Put it in for ten minutes only:

[image]

[image]

10 mins!

[image]

Take it out (don't burn your fingers) and put a few room-temperature eggs on top:

[image]

[image]

For the remaining four minutes ...

[image]

## Result - about as good as it gets with a frozen-pizza, it seems?

Soft but cooked whites and yolks, a bit runny.

[image]

[image]

How to make it better?

I'm thinking it's probably better to not break the yolks.

It's not so easy to do these tests, I can't eat frozen pizza every day!

It's tough to do say 3 with untouched yolks and three where you break the yolk a little.

Intriguingly as a couple of astute writers pointed out on the earlier question: modern food-science frozen-pizzas are *so* carefully worked out that if you toss anything on top (perhaps a little extra cheese or veg) it really does affect the cooking, so perhaps add a minute when you have eggs (or anything) on top.

#### The big question ...

Can or perhaps should one wait ***even longer*** before adding the eggs?

After all, the pizza can only get more and more scalding hot, and have more and more heat reservoir.

What is the ideal time/temp to cook eggs on "extremely hot bread" ?

Total triumph by the "team" that pointed out on the other question that surprisingly the eggs go negative if you put them on the icy pizza. Wow. I would never have guessed, it's incredible.  The difference is amazing if you do two runs to compare.

Comment: Can you comment or edit in how melted/liquid the cheese is after the 10 min? If it were melted and bubbling (and with sufficient cheese - you might need a cheese pizza for this), perhaps the eggs would fry on the cheese and cook from the oven? BTW, great to see a follow-up and some real experimentation based on answers.

Comment: That's a great question.   I will have to investigate that next pizza ...  Thanks!

Comment: Interesting results! Better how? Can you be clearer on the result you are trying to achieve with the eggs?

Comment: hi @GdD sure, TBC if you put the eggs on at the start, they are essentially "totally uncooked" and useless, just a runny mass, barely warmed up.  (See the earlier related question!). The difference is surprising, almost amazing.

Comment: @Fattie I understand, that runny eggs are not what you want. Now you found out how to make pizza with non-runny eggs, what more is there to improve? I'm unfamiliar with egg on pizza, should they be crispy?

Answer (score 3):

It does seem a bit counterintuitive, but your original method would have chilled or even partially frozen the eggs. A pizza base isn't a good conductor of heat so you would have been relying on getting heat into the toppings through the cold egg. OTOH egg cooks quite easily in the heat from the hot toppings, which is why it works better.

I'd guess that if your oven's "420F" and rate of radiant heat delivery match those used in testing the product (they won't perfectly, but it might be quite close) you'll need another minute or two. TBH that's within the preference range for how browned different people like their pizza. Assuming you like your pizza toppings fairly browned, I'd next try 12 minutes, adding the egg (yolk broken or not, depending on your preference) then another 4 with the egg. Some of the heat comes from the pizza, some from the oven, and how quickly you work will make a difference as the surface of the pizza will cool rapidly. So it's best to have the eggs already broken in a cup, and tip them on immediately.

With whole yolks, if you eat your pizza with a knife and fork, you can dip the crust in the runny yolk. Restaurants in France serve pizzas like this (they give you a steak knife), but rely purely on the heat from the pizza to cook the egg, rather than returning it to the oven. Of course their pizza ovens are hotter than a domestic oven.

Comment: ahh .. duh .. some heat from the pizza, of course.  Yes ideally I like the yolks Not broken (the only reason I ever tried breaking them was to help them cook, when I was trying the (what is now known to be) completely useless method of eggs at the beginning!) "So it's best to have the eggs already broken in a cup, and tip them on immediately." indeed i always do that with eggs in all situations!  and indeed always leave them out of the fridge for an hour or two

Comment: {You know a couple of folks have mentioned how in France they add the egg after the pizza's out; you know, I wouldn't say that's universal (ie in France) but sure. (Anyway France is so regional ... and the joint near my place (Bourgogne) is an Italian family anyway!) }

Comment: the bottom line here is I really think with the procedure in question, LESS THEN FOUR MINUTES (and no need to break the yolk) may work perfectly well. (As I mentioned, it's not "that" easy to go test these things, i don't have heston blumenthal time and resources, heh!  I will try to get to it in coming weeks ...)

Comment: Good point about France. Most of my experience is from the sort of pizzeria/crêperie/grill places you get in Brittany and the Loire valley, though I ate plenty of pizza when I went to Nice and the effect was the same.

Comment: I'm highly in favor of eating as much as possible in Brittany & Loire!!  :)